Pierdo los eventos de clic y selección al actualizar solo un punto en la gráfica plolty js
Estoy utilizando una gráfica plotly js con angular y TypeScript, y al actualizar el color de un punto pierdo los eventos de clic y selección y ya no puedo actualizar un segundo punto.



<plotly-plot #chart divId="grafica" (selected)="automaticPopUp($event)" (plotlyClick)="automaticPopUp($event)" [data]="grafica.data"
        [layout]="grafica.layout" [config]="grafica.config" [useResizeHandler]="true"
        [style]="{position: 'relative', width: '100%', height: '100%'}"></plotly-plot>



el código dentro de la funcion automaticPopUp:


if ( event && event.points && event.points.length > 0 ) {

        for (let i = 0; i < event.points.length; i++) {
          const point = event.points[i];
          const pointNumber = point.pointNumber;
          const curveNumber = point.curveNumber;
          
          this.grafica.data[curveNumber].marker.color[pointNumber] = 'red';

          Plotlyjs.restyle('grafica', {'marker.color': [this.grafica.data[curveNumber].marker.color]}, [curveNumber]);
        }
      }



